# git not detecting directory moved into another directory

Tags: git, ignore, mv

Given a file `foo/example.txt`, git doesn't seem to detect the new file when it's moved into a newly created parent directory, i.e. `foo/bar/example.txt`, by moving the directory.

```
mkdir foo/bar
mv foo foo/bar
```

In particular, `git status` shows that `foo/example.txt` is deleted, but not that `foo/bar/example.txt` is create. `git status --ignored` will show `foo/bar` as an ignored dir, even though it's *not* in `.gitignore`. In fact, even renaming the directory doesn't change its ignored status.

This *doesn't* happen when using `git mv`. I don't understand why.

This is git version `2.13.0` on `Darwin C02RW05YFVH6 15.6.0`.

Answer (score 3):

It will *detect* it when you `git rm` the old directory and `git add` the new one.

Comment: Why? And is there a setting to make Git always detect such changes without extra steps?

Comment: The thing is that you "moved" the directory behind git's back. If right after moving the directory (without using git) you had checked status git would have told you something like "this directory is missing... and there's this other directory I don't know anything about is also there". That should be enough to make you realize that git noticed there's something fishy. If at this point you had "added" the directory git would think the files are "new" because you wouldn't have notified git about the removal. If after adding you had deleted the old directory then git would say "aha!".... 2bcont

Comment: ... and it would then tell you that the files have been moved..... _or_ instead of using "mv; git add; git rm", you could have let git do the movement for you and you would get the same result in a single shot: ```git mv originaldir bar/newdir```

Comment: > and there's this other directory I don't know anything about is also there That's the thing, Git *ignores* the new dir. Is that expected behavior?

Comment: yep. It will show up as a directory with "untracked" files inside (git will report that on status).